# How to access AspNetUserRoles table in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I use Identity 2 in my project and I Want display the list of AspNetUserRoles in the view. but I can not access to this table from DB object.how to access this table in ASP.NET MVC 5 !?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it a code-first application? Do you have a database with that table in it and are there more than 2 columns it that table?

Comment: Yes it's code -first.and it Has two columns(RoleId and UserId) @Ghukas

Comment: I did not try anything just i want to access to this table from DB object in Controller @SimonPrice

Comment: `AspNetUserRoles` table is a mapping table. You can access the table using `AspNetUser` object or `AspNetRole` object. Assuming you want to show all users and their roles, you can do that by getting it from `var userRoles = user.AspNetRoles;` for each of the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a list of all users and their roles.

Give your context name

```
using(var context = new YourContextName())
{
    var usersAndRoles = new List<UserRoleModel>(); // Adding this model just to have it in a nice list.
    var users = context.AspNetUsers;

    foreach(var user in users)
    {        
        foreach(var role in user.Roles)
        {
            usersAndRoles.Add(new UserRoleModel
            {
                UserName = user.UserName,
                RoleName = role.Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, there can be a more optimal way.

Comment: This will possibly execute a single query for users and then, for each user, an extra query for its roles. Consider using Include to reduce the number of queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the following model on the view where you want to retrieve the User Roles.

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>
```

Then you only have to do a foreach of the Model and take his Name attribute (item.Name) it will return and show e.g. Admin, Employee, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = Context.AspNetUserRole.ToList();
```